# tbb-nightly-hardened provides no TCP socks proxy, only unix domain socket. is that normal?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, socks, torsocks

I noticed when trying the nightly hardened that the TBB now doesn't spawn an TCP socks proxy but rather use a unix domain sockets is that to be the expected behavior for the future of TBB hardened ? (i used to socksify other app trough tor using the default socket (localhost:9150) that was spawn with TBB standard)

Answer (score 1):

The feature has been introduced to make it possible to block all IP networking, thereby, making it harder to bypass Tor. Tickets [12585](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12585) and [14270](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/14270) have some more information on it.

So, yes, this is the expected future behavior of Tor Browser hardened. I wouldn't be surprised when the regular Tor Browser switched to unix sockets at some point too.